# How to add variable in tkinter treeview widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need to add the value of another command into the value of a Treeview widget in tkinter but when i try the value in the gui ends up just saying "none".

```
output = print("hello")
tree.insert('', 'end', text="1", values=(output, '' , '',''))
```

How can i add the value of this variable into widget?

Comment: The `print()` function doesn't return a value, or more specifically it returns `None`. If you want to insert the string `"hello"` in the treeview, try setting your variable to a string literal, e.g. `output = "hello"`

Answer (score 0):

> but when i try the value in the gui ends up just saying "none".

Change this:

```
output = print("hello")
tree.insert('', 'end', text="1", values=(output, '' , '',''))
```

to:

```
output = "hello"
tree.insert('', 'end', text="1", values=output)
```

You will see Hello in first column.